# Top Level Menu Item Slipping Down When Child Displayed

Tags: css, menu

Hello i have made a menu. Its the black ugly looking thing below the top fixed menu. You can view it [HERE](http://onlineplac.es/latest) or on any page that you visit on my website. Its the one that has Chat News Lifestyle QI Home Life Sport Tech menu items.

Some items have child menu items. You can see it best when you click the 'sport' item. Actually thats the only one with child items at the moment.

As you can see the 'tech' menu item falls down the bottom when sport is clicked and the children are shown. Can anyone suggest a fix for me so as the top memu items stay on the top at all times?

If you go deeper in 'sport' under 'ice hockey'  have a temp link to 'american football'. I was hoping that that would stay on the 3rd layer of things leaving the top 2 errr layers sitting pretty.

Could anyone help me out at all please? Ive been fiddling with it for a while and i have to finally admit defeat.

Thanks

```
#block-menu-menu-categories ul {
    text-align: center;
}


#block-menu-menu-categories ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

menu, ol, ul, .item-list ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: also on a sort of sidenote, possibly related, i cant seem to get the child menu items to have a bit of spacec above them when they are on display. Im picking up css ok after a good few years of tinkering but listitems have always troubled me. i just cant get a grip of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `display` type

```
#block-menu-menu-categories ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
```

Add `display: inline;` to this element as shown above.

Comment: a brillian thanks Vector. That seems to have sorted things out a little more for me. now my child items seem to be appearing on the top line along with my top level items. Is there any way to fix this? I really appreciate your help as it would take me all night and i still wont have fixed. I know i should learn css more but i do try. Ive got a million and one other things i need to learn with my site. I do learn as i go. thanks

Comment: shall i mark this as fixed and start a new issue on how to display the child items below? I suppose my question on how to stop the top menu items has been answered. I just kinda thought that my child menus would stay below as it was before.